# iPad Pro size classes

Tags: xcode, ipad, interface-builder, size-classes, ios9.1

In Xcode 7.1 beta 1 only the usual `compact` and `regular` size classes are available—in Interface Builder and in code.

Will there be new size classes coming for the iPad Pro? It would also be interesting to know which size classes apps will have in the various split-screen setups.

Comment: See the latest Xcode build.

Comment: Which one do you mean? There are no new size classes in Xcode 7.1 beta 1 (from Sep. 9th). And I couldn't find a newer build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, iPad Pro uses the same size classes (regular) as iPad.

I found the following text in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html):

> iPad (including iPad Pro) uses the regular size class in both dimensions and in both orientations. In other words, the iPad display environment is always horizontally and vertically regular.

Comment: This is really... unsatisfying. I thought we are supposed to rely on size classes from now on and shouldn't discriminate by view sizes anymore. How are we supposed to build custom interfaces for larger devices then? But obviously Apple also violates these guidelines (see `UISplitViewController`...)

Comment: Yea a bit confusing to me as well :) Seems like the size classes is only thought for 5.5" iPhone.

Comment: my guess is that it mostly works for multitasking splitview right now the iPad is in landscape mode H:Compact in 1/4 and 1/2 for the iPad Pro I think it might change to H:Compact in 1/4 and H:Regular in 1/2

Comment: Guess you will be using a lot of >= and <= constraints to differentiate between your layouts for iPad Pro and smaller iPads.

Comment: @peacetype can you give an example? I'm struggling with position, using constant values, which is ok on all iPads except pro.

Comment: @Jules - I have the same problem designing for iPhone 4, 5 & 6 sizes in portrait (all the same size class). I add multiple constraints for each element that I want to respond to changes in screen size. So I determine the exact position of an element for the smallest screen size and set a constraint to be >= to that position. Then I create another constraint for the larger screen size and for that constraint say the position should be <= the exact position I want the element to be on the larger screen size. iOS uses whichever constraint will fit the user's screen, be it a large or small screen.